# Reading Optocouplers datasheet: current transfer ratio (CTR)

Tags: transistors, analog, opto-isolator

So I am working with an [optocoupler](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-0752EN) at the moment, and having trouble understanding what CTR value to use in my calculations.

The datasheet states 50% Min and 600% Max, which is a huge difference. Do we always take the minimum for our IC/IF equation? Or do we take it from a graph? Its not clear on this datasheet

Answer (score 3):

You need to be sure your circuit works for any value of CTR between 50 and 600%.

If you're verifying your circuit in a simulator, you should test it with both extreme values, and maybe an in between value too.

Comment: When it comes to ordering the actual parts, you can choose binned parts with a tighter CTR spec. So if you're prepared to spend more you could verify your design with less extreme values.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the datasheet, it looks like the current transfer ratio is *also* dependent on the forward current as well as the voltage.

Figure 13 (Current Transfer Ratio vs. Forward Current) shows that.

Answer (score 2):

It'll be be necessary to use the minimum CTR given (50%) for proper circuit operation. Ensure that the upper limit doesn't give you a problem.

It's important to note that many semiconductors have rather broad specs. Current gain for a small signal transistor, for example, may vary as widely as 150 to 900. You can either buy the broad spec one or in many cases a selected part may prove beneficial to you. Loads of Pro-Electron transistors e.g. BC548 for example have A. B and C gain ranks and many Japanese devices have 'colour' gain ranks, e.g ORG (orange), GRN (green), BLU (blue!). Similarly some power devices have A, B, C, even D voltage ranks.

In the case of an optocoupler you're subject to 2 variables. The luminous flux of the emitter diode and the sensitivity of the receptor diode (junction). So the apparently wide CTR of 12:1 is only a difference of 3.5:1 for each part of the device.

In volume manufacture it's often possible (if you need) to get parts selected to your spec although it's inadvisable to rely on this.